# Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have a problem while creating the **Asp.Net MVC** project on visual studio 2022. Project is created with an error message.

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Project is opened but unable to build, build failed and pop up appear with message.

> Build failed, Do you want to continue debugging.

Error Images are given bellow.
[Build Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWY7M.jpg)
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wCb3.jpg)

I have tried multiple mentioned solutions but failed to resolve the issue. Following are the solutions which I have tried but failed.

**Solution 1:**

1. Close the VS.
2. Delete the cash folder having name `ProjectTemplatesCache` and `ComponentModelCache`.
3. Reset the Visual Studio Setting.
   `Tools>Import and export settings>reset all settings`

**Solution 2:**

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Go to the project's root folder and delete the .vs directory.
3. Start Visual Studio and open the solution.
4. The build should now work.

**Solution 3:**

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Start —> Run —> `regsvr32  %SystemRoot%\System32\msxml3.dll`
3. Start —> Run —> `regsvr32  %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\msxml3.dll`
4. Open Visual Studio Project, it will work.

**Solution 4:**

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Uninstall the visual studio and all its temp folders.
3. Reboot the system.
4. Reinstall the visual studio.
5. Get same error, failed to resolve it.